# Is it safe to do "RmDir /r $INSTDIR" in NSIS?

Tags: installation, nsis

I noticed this warning in the documentation for NSIS's `RmDir` method:

> Warning: using RMDir /r $INSTDIR in
>   the uninstaller is not safe. Though it
>   is unlikely, the user might select to
>   install to the Program Files folder
>   and so this command will wipe out the
>   entire Program Files folder, including
>   other programs that has nothing to do
>   with the uninstaller.

This scares me, since up until now I had not considered this possibility and I had that exact line in my script.  But when I tested if this would happen by installing my program to a pre-existing location containing pre-existing files and then running my uninstaller with `RmDir /r /REBOOTOK $INSTDIR` in it, the existing files were left unharmed.

Is this an outdated warning?  I'm using NSIS v. 2.46.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RmDir /r will delete the whole directory tree if it can, so it is "unsafe". See http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Uninstall_only_installed_files for a way to only delete the files you install

Comment: What if I were to create a sub folder at $INSTDIR and put all my program data in there, recursively delete that sub dir, and then do a regular RmDir on the original $INSTDIR?

Comment: Well, it would help, but the issue could still be there. Lets say your subfolder is named system32 and the user installs to %windir%, you will then delete %windir%\system32

Comment: I think I'll risk it with creating a subdir inside INSTDIR named: <program_name-version>... I think this should work.

Comment: The code example doesn't appear to remove the $INSTDIR. Should I just leave the directory there, or is there a safe way of doing this?

Comment: This method of uninstalling only installed files is too complicated. I know that's my opinion, and I really think there should be an easier way to do this. It's too prone to errors and takes too many lines of code.

Comment: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Validating_$INSTDIR_before_uninstall
"What if $INSTDIR is empty because the registry key is missing? "$INSTDIR" will become "" which means that everything from the system root could be deleted INCLUDING THE OPERATING SYSTEM."

Answer (score 1):

RMDir on a directory without /r (recursive) flag will remove the directory if it is empty. At some point they have added this feature, not sure when.

[NSIS Scripting Reference - RMDir](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.1.8)